# Remove frame from plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am making a single plot.  I am using the code below.  There are 5 bars in the plot.  There is a black rectangle that surrounds the bars.  I don't want that black rectangle to be there.  How do I remove it from the plot?

```
mydata['var'].plot(kind='barh',linewidth=0,width=.9)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `edgecolor=None` parameter while calling the plot function.

```
mydata['var'].plot(kind='barh', linewidth=0, width=.9, edgecolor=None)
```